# Typescript + React: passing class as external function arg

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some functions that I would like to reuse as methods across different React classes that are compatible. Is it possible in Typescript to pass the class to a function and have it correctly typed?

I want to do something like this...

```
// function to be reused across classes
const func = (class: [class type]) => this.setState({ key: "value" })

// class 1 that calls the function in a method
class Foo extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  callFunc = () => {
    func(this)
  }
  ...
}

// class 2 that calls the function in a method
class Bar extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  callFunc = () => {
    func(this)
  }
  ...
}
```

I had this working in JS, but moving to typescript, I am failing to get the proper type in the `func` args for the classes. I can see that it would have to be some kind of union type to allow for specific classes but IDK how to accomplish it. Any ideas?

Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: why not just `const func = (cls: React.Component) => cls.setState({ key: "value" })` ? do you require specific fields on the state to be present in the class ? Then just specify them on the state generic parameter: `const func = (cls: React.Component<any, {key: string}>) => cls.setState({ key: "value" })
`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir your method gets me halfway there. What if I wanted to access other user defined methods or attributes on the class besides the builtin `setState`?

Comment: You would need to add them to your parameter type, `const func = (cls: React.Component<any, {key: string}> & { method(): void }) =>  cls.method`

Answer (score 1):

The function argument needs to specify the contract that needs to be implemented by the client classes. In this case the parameter should be a `React.Component` that has certain fields in state, and also may have some methods that the function will use. To get the extra methods we can use an intersection type (`A & B`) to specify that the parameter is a `React.Component` with some extra methods.

```
// function to be reused across classes
const func = (cls: React.Component<any, { key: string, optionalKey?: string }> & { requiredMethod(): void; optionalMethod?(): void}) => {
  cls.setState({ key: "value" })
  cls.requiredMethod();
  if(cls.optionalMethod)cls.optionalMethod();
}

// class 1 that calls the function in a method
class Foo extends React.Component<{}, { key: string }> {
  callFunc = () => {
    func(this)
  }
  requiredMethod(){}
}

// class 2 that calls the function in a method
class Bar extends React.Component<{}, {key: string, optionalKey: string }> {
  callFunc = () => {
    func(this)
  }

  requiredMethod(){}
  optionalMethod(){}
}
```